# What will happen if we have a private constructor in the class?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

What will happen if we have a private constructor in the class?
(in Java)

Comment: What happened when you tried the same?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do next.

Comment: welcome to SO. Please spend some time in reading the FAQ.  Your question does not show any research effort, nor has any value for future visitor.   Short answer is when constructor is private, object of the class can be constructed only from class, making it singleton like case.  But much depends on what you want.

Comment: @Jayan No reason it needs to be a singleton.

Comment: @ Dave Newton - ofcourse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that (without reflection) constructor wont be accessible outside of your class so other classes wont be able to call it. Only members of your class will be bale to create its object.

```
class A{
    private A(){} //private constructor

    private static A a = new A(); //you can create A object as a field

    void test(){
        new A(); // you can create A object inside methods of your class
    }

    class Inner{ // inner classes are also members of outer class so you can use 
                 // A constructor here
        A a = new A(); //OK
        void test(){
            new A(); //OK
        }
    }
}

class B{
    A a = new A();//error: we don't have access to A constructor
}
```

Comment: what if constructor of inner class is made private, does it be accessed by the outer class?

Comment: @DivyanshuKumar Yes. One of main reasons we use nested/inner types is that they have full access to members (and constructors) of outer class and vice-versa, Outer class has full access to everything in Inner/Nested classes (regardless of their visibility).

Answer (score 2):

You can only use that constructor within the current class.

Answer (score 0):

You will only be able to call it from other constructors in the class, or from static methods in the class.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally a way of restrict creation of object from this class. This means you cannot create object from the class.